# Calculating the mean squared error for an estimate of a large sum

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, estimation-theory, expectation

Consider the set of all Boolean function $f: \{0, 1\}^{n} \rightarrow \{-1, 1\}$. Now, let's pick a function uniformly at random from this set. Let $F$ be the random variable corresponding to the randomly picked function. Define

\begin{equation}
p = \left(\sum_{x \in \{0, 1\}^{n}} \frac{F(x)}{2^{n}}\right)^{2}.
\end{equation}

After randomly picking the function, consider the following estimation strategy:

- Pick $k$ strings $\mathcal{K} =\{x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_k\}$, where each $x_i \in \{0, 1\}^{n}$ and the strings are picked with replacement.
- Evaluate and output the estimate
  \begin{equation}
  q = \left(\sum_{x \in \mathcal{K}} \frac{F(x)}{2^{n}}\right)^{2} + \frac{2^{n} -k}{4^{n}}.
  \end{equation}

Note that
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[p] = \mathbb{E}[q] = \frac{1}{2^{n}},
\end{equation}
where the expectation is taken over both the random choice of the function $f$ and the randomness in the estimation procedure.

I am trying to calculate the expected mean squared error (or, at the very least, I'm trying to find upper and lower bounds that are as tight as possible) which is defined as
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}\left[(p-q)^{2}\right],
\end{equation}
where the expectation is again taken over both the random choice of the function $f$ and the randomness in the estimation procedure.

My intuition is that the error should be extremely large, if $k$ is small, as the estimation procedure only "sees" $k$ places of an exponentially large sum.

However, I could not make this precise.

Equivalently, I think the correlation between $p$ and $q$ should be very small, but I could not prove this either. That is, I expect
\begin{equation}
\frac{\text{Covariance}(p, q)}{\sqrt{\text{Variance}(p) \cdot \text{Variance}(q)}}
\end{equation}
to be sufficiently small --- perhaps exponentially decreasing with $n$.

---

For simplicity, let's say that we can assume $n$ is very large, and we can approximate the probability mass functions with appropriate probability density functions.

Comment: Why is $\hat{p}$ an estimate for $p$? That estimate has $E[p-\hat{p}]<0$; it would achieve $p=\hat{p}$ only if the unobserved values of $F$ are all equal to $1$. I'd expect an estimate of $$q = \left(\sum_{x \in \mathcal{K}} \frac{F(x)}{2^{n}}\right)^{2} +  \frac{2^{n} -k}{4^{n}}$$ instead, which has $E[p-q]=0$.

Comment: @MattF. Yes, you are indeed right. $q$ is a better estimate. I have updated the question. My intuition is that the mean squared error should still be sufficiently large, since it should not be possible to have a good estimation of an exponentially large sum with only polynomially many samples.